# Load external site with PHP without breaking relative links in that site

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have a php page where I'm trying to load and then echo and external page, (which is sitting in the same server but in complete different path/domain, if that matters).

I've tried using both `file_get_contents()` and `curl`. They both correctly load the html of the target page, the problem is that it's not displaying correctly because that target page has relative links to several files (images, css, javascript).

Is there any way I can accomplish this with PHP? If not, what would be the next best way? The target site must look like it's being loaded from the initial page (URL-wise), I don't want to do a redirect.

So, the browser would show http://example.com/initial-page.php even though its contents come from http://example2.com/target-page.php

EDIT:
This is something that could easily be done with an iframe but I want to avoid that too for several reasons, one of them is because with and iframe it breaks the responsiveness of the target site. I can't change the code of the target site to fix that either.

Comment: Since this is a rather unorthodox method to get the contents of HTML on the same server, I think you will have to be unorthodox in how you handle it. You *Could* use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on the contents of the return of `file_get_contents()` to toggle those relative paths to their full path. Maybe something like `preg_replace("$\/", "http://example.com/", $pagecontent)` (that might not be 100%, but it's in the ballpark).

Comment: @JNevill I did think about that but the target site has scripts that also load stuff using relative paths and I don't think I could fix that with this method, but thanks!

Comment: You could add the [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag to specify the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document like so `<base href="http://example.com" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution was a combination of what I was trying to do (using `curl`) and what **WebRookie** suggested using the `base` html tag in the page being loaded via curl.

In my particular case, I pass the *base URL* as a parameter in `curl` and I echo it in the loaded page, allowing me to load that same page from different websites (which was another reason why I wanted to do this).